# Omniture capture a traffic variable without associated visit or page metrics

Tags: analytics, adobe-analytics

I need to track a single traffic variable (a "prop") on a 3rd party site that is embedding our content.

We don't want the Omniture call to increment a visit or page view or any other metric that is normally captured by the s code library.

The 3rd party site on which we're capturing the prop variable will need to track this in the client, so using the data insertion API is not an option.

How to achieve this? Would a s.tl() method do this? i.e. not count a visit, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a s.tl() call would not work. Even though that call does not increment a page view, any "first" call made will register a visitor and a visit. What I mean by that is even if a standard visit begins with a s.tl() call as opposed to a s.t() call, which ever one happens first will start the visitor and visit being counted.

What you are looking for is called a Light Server Call. This allows you to fire a call and capture some variables but will not register a page view, visit, or visitor. Plus they cost much less than a standard server call. You will need to work with Client Care to get it set up and implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by making an image request that looks something like:

`< img src='http://somersid.122.2o7.net/b/ss/somersid/1/H.XX.X--NS/0?c[some_prop]=data     height='1' width='1'  alt='' />`

This is the first I've heard of Light Server Calls. Can't find anything about them in the documentation. Thanks.